# Should the 7805 part number in the title be corrected?

Tags: discussion, editing

It turns out that the part in the question [Generating negative voltage rail using 7805](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454778/generating-negative-voltage-rail-using-7805) is a **P**7805, which is a DC-to-DC converter,  not a linear voltage regulator.

I notice that no-one has changed the part number in the question's title - is that deliberate or just that no-one's done it yet? (I know I've missed editing a title elsewhere lots of times when editing the body of a question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. And the comments and answers based on the misreading have been cleaned up.

Comment: Is that wise? OPs entire question relies on them thinking it's a regular 7805, AND the answer OP lifted that from states using a 780x regulator, not specifying it's a P7805 except for the image. Changing the question and removing the answers doesn't actually address that.

Comment: @Passerby: It appeared to me that the OP understood exactly what he had, and was simply sloppy about writing the title of the question. As a result, many of the comments and answers started off on the wrong foot.